# Получить value текущего элемента

Tags: jquery

Есть список товаров, и кнопки количества товаров у каждого товара.

```
  <div class="button-group">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="number">
        <button class="minus">-</button>
        <input type="text" value="1" size="2" id="input-quantity"/>
        <button class="plus">+</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="bttn1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_wishlist }}" onclick="wishlist.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="bttn2" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ button_cart }}</span></button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

При отправке в корзину нужно получить количество товаров из input атрибута value.
Если сделать так

```
var singleValue = $("#input-quantity").val()
```

то получаю значение только первого товара в списке.
А как получить значение value у нужного элемента?

Comment: Виктор, уточните какие `id` формируются у других `input`. А тот поиск, который делаете вы происходит по id, который должен быть уникален для каждого элемента. Возможный вариант решения, если вы замените `id` на `class`, то все заработает.

Comment: id формируются одинаковые.Заменил на class все равно не работает(

Comment: может как-то через родительский класс, типа .this только я синтаксиса не знаю

Comment: а если id у каждого товара будет уникальный тогда как можно решить?

Comment: @Виктор, а как ты меняешь `input.value`?  Откуда берешь данные?

Comment: @Air, по умолчанию в html value="1". То есть, по умолчанию в корзину добавляется 1 товар

Answer (score 0):

Поиск осуществляется внутри `div` с классом `number`:

```
<div class="number"> //по этому диву
    <button class="minus">-</button>
    <input type="text" value="1" size="2" id="input-quantity"/>
    <button class="plus">+</button>
</div>
```

А в javascript изменяет добавление данных на цикл по всем элементам с этим классом:

```
var singleValue = []; //объявление массива
$('.number input').each(function() {
singleValue.push($(this).val()); //добавление каждого значения из input с классом
});

console.log(singleValue); //пример вывода вашего значения
```